# How to create a document on a server in another Lotus Notes network?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, agent

Public Domino server has a publicly available Lotus Notes database. That database has a form that an unauthenticated user can fill out and submit using his/her browser.

This publicly available form is only used for the post request and data must not be stored on that publicly available server. Instead, I need to connect to a database on an internal server and create the document there.

Obvious solution is a Lotus Script agent but when I worked on Notes, I remember non-user agents were prevented from opening databases on another server for security reasons. I certainly cannot introduce secure server setup. I need to find a way to do this that fits current setup. The servers are in two different Notes networks but mail is routed between them, so if I don't find a better solution, I will probably mail the document.

Any ideas? I have not worked with latest Notes servers. Anything in 8.5 that can help here?

Answer (score 3):

In the server document on the security tab there is an Option called "Trusted Servers" if you could put the external server into that field, then the agent would be allowed to dirctly write into databases on the internal server.
If you are not able / allowed to do this, then you have to write to a "local" database (on external server) and replicate this database to internal server either by using a console command (NotesSession.SendConsoleCommand) or with the replicate method of the NotesDatabase class (not sure, if this will work due to the same security restrictions) or via scheduled replication.

If the database itself cannot be replicated on the external server, then you should use a container database and let an agent on the internal server copy the data to the internal database.

And the last possibility you already mentioned: compose the document and send it via mail. Make the target database a mailin- database and simply send you data there with NotesDocument.Send...

One of these options should solve your problem.

Comment: FYI - here is an IBM technote on the Trusted Server feature: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21086111